# How do I Iterate my variable in an OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java and Android,
I would like to know how do I increment the cardVar variable ?

```
public class xyz{


private void getLevelData(final CourseDataClass courseData) {

    int cardVar = 0;
    int levelVar=0;

    courseLevel = courseData.getCourseLevelClassList().get(levelVar);

    proceedChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int finalCardVar = cardVar;
            long levelId = courseLevel.getLevelId();
            int courseId = courseLevel.getLpId();
            long cardId = courseLevel.getCourseCardClassList().get(finalCardVar).getCardId();

            String getCardUrl = OustSdkApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.getCard_url);
            getCardUrl = getCardUrl.replace("cardId", String.valueOf(cardId));
            getCardUrl = getCardUrl.replace("{courseId}", String.valueOf(courseId));
            getCardUrl = getCardUrl.replace("{levelId}", String.valueOf(levelId));

            try{
                final String finalGetCardUrl = getCardUrl;
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            OustRestClient oustRestClient=new OustRestClient();
                            LearningCardResponce learningCardResponce=oustRestClient.downloadCardData(finalGetCardUrl);
                            Log.d(TAG,"learningCardResponse");
                            gotResponse(learningCardResponce);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

I want to set my cardVar to 0 initialy and then after the thread method ends,want to increment its value so that whenever the OnClickListener in called, it increments the value of cardVar by 1

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just add `cardVar++;` at the end of your Thread

Answer (score 0):

You can add your variable as a method attribute. It will be accessible inside the `OnClickListener`.

```
public class xyz{

private int cardVar = 0;

private void getLevelData(final CourseDataClass courseData) {

    int levelVar=0;

    courseLevel = courseData.getCourseLevelClassList().get(levelVar);

    proceedChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // DO YOUR STUFF
            cardVar++;
        }
    }
}
```

Best

Comment: If it's working for you, don't forget to mark the topic as answered :)